# Aviary won't load

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, aviary

I'm working on project that utilises Aviary Web SDK, but while creating test page I encountered serious problem. Aviary won't load. There is only progress indicator visible whole time, and no action can be performed.

This is code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aviary test - website</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/imaging/v3/editor.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
                apiKey:  'ba65b30f0f844465bba58d7b1b644d69',
                theme:   'dark',
                tools:   'overlays,enhance,redeye',
                onLoad:  function() {
                    alert("Aviary loaded!");

                    featherEditor.launch({
                        image: 'editableimage1',
                        url: 'xyz.png'
                    });
                },
                onSave:  function(imageID, newURL) {
                    var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
                    img.src = newURL;
                },
                onerror: function(errObj) {
                    alert();
                }
            });

            function launchEditor(id, src) {
                featherEditor.launch({
                    image: id,
                    url: src
                });
                return false;
            }

            $(function() {
                //alert("Document loaded");
                //setTimeout(function() { launchEditor("editableimage1", "xyz.png"); }, 500);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="return launchEditor('editableimage1', 'xyz.png');">Edit!</a>
        <img id="editableimage1" src="xyz.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

In addition here is a link for test page: http://sprynter.tk/Aviary/aviary_test.html

In addition to this I checked everything I was able to check:

- I have proper apiKey generated on Adobe Creative SDK page
- Image is loaded before aviary is loaded
- Image was 509 x 255 px (now is 100 x 100 px) to be sure that it's isn't too big
- I attached functions to every callbacks (onLoad, onSave, onError) to be sure that events run

And still nothing...